Fetch plain text from ubuntu pastebin using terminal Ubuntu Server
i'm building an Nginx server using Ubuntu Server inside a VM in VirtualBox. As I can't paste text inside the terminal (I guess because Ubuntu Server doesn't offer GUI), I want to download the Nginx configuration from a pastebin service.
The snippet is here: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BnNGY37G4D/plain/
I've tried with wget, curl and lynx, but with no success:
Output for sudo wget https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BnNGY37G4D/plain/

Output for lynx -dump https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BnNGY37G4D/plain/

And curl https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BnNGY37G4D/plain/ gives no output.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

If I open that link a private tab, it asks me to login, so it looks like you can't access it without authentication

That said, why not just setup SSH in your VM, and then connect via SSH to it from your host system's terminal? Then you can copy or paste whatever you want, and you can also use scp, rsync, whatever to upload/download config files or anything else, really.

@muru You're right... I expected that Ubuntu's Pastebin to be public. Now I've tried using pastebin.com and works as expected using curl. Thanks! I was thinking about using SSH, too. But I thought it would be easier to implement using pastebin. And thanks to the idea of scp and rsync, I'm a bit noob in Linux and I didn't know about them.

As @muru said, it was because of Ubuntu's pastebin needs authentication to access to it's raw content. Changing to pastebin.com solved my problem.
